# How to set up acts_as_follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, rubygems

I'm using the gem acts_as_follower in a rails app. I set it up and it works (In console), however I'm clueless as to how to set it up in a view. 
I want to make a button correspond to the user.follow and user.stop_following methods.

The github doesn't explain this. Help please.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the gem, it's basic Rails stuff. If I were you, I'd get a good Rails book. Books are good, they are structured knowledge.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create controller actions that you link to.  For example in an app I have the following two actions added to a user controller.  Once the routes are also setup I use the url helpers to link to the actions from my view, and end up displaying the flash messages via javascript callbacks.

UsersController:

```
def follow
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if current_user
    if current_user == @user
      flash[:error] = "You cannot follow yourself."
    else
      current_user.follow(@user)
      RecommenderMailer.new_follower(@user).deliver if @user.notify_new_follower
      flash[:notice] = "You are now following #{@user.monniker}."
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = "You must <a href='/users/sign_in'>login</a> to follow #{@user.monniker}.".html_safe
  end
end

def unfollow
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if current_user
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
    flash[:notice] = "You are no longer following #{@user.monniker}."
  else
    flash[:error] = "You must <a href='/users/sign_in'>login</a> to unfollow #{@user.monniker}.".html_safe
  end
end
```

config/route.rb:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :follow
    get :unfollow
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can use the url helper to link to the controller action:

```
<%= link_to "Unfollow", unfollow_user_path(@user) %>
```

Comment: In my view I have <%= button_to("Un-Follow", "unfollow") %> however when i click on the generated button I just get No route matches [POST] "/users/unfollow"

Comment: Did you add the member routes to your route.rb file like I've shown in the second code block?  You don't appear to actually be passing in any user id to unfollow.  You should be able to use it as <%= button_to "Unfollow", unfollow_user_path(@user) %>

Comment: Thank you so much... Unfortunately button_to doesn't work the same way as link_to.

Comment: Hey @JDutil, i'm stuck a long time now on this, i tried your method but i think i keep messing up the Code. I opened a question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761563/get-started-with-set-up-acts-as-follower . Do you mind Giving it a look ? Thanks :)

Comment: Following my code should work fine except that it was written prior to Rails 4 so you may need to make adjustments for Rails 4 changes.

Comment: @JDutil whats interesting is that you don't set a view for this? Followed this setup and when i clicked the `un-follow` it renders a missing template method error. Shouldn't you be rendering a template?

Comment: I don't readily have the projects code anymore, but what was happening is a .js.erb template would be rendered and just switch link from follow/unfollow.  Similar to what I do in these js templates for a favoriting system thats favorites/unfavorites items https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_favorites/tree/master/app/views/spree/favorites

Comment: Very well written and easy to follow - using Rails 4. Nice one!